# When running a method with a Timer().schedule() delay it crashes my application

Tags: android, kotlin

I am having an issue with my code. I am building a 0-60 timer and want it to flash and display the recoded time when the current Progress is equal to 60. However at the moment when ever my app goes to run the code with in the when statement it crashes. I am not very familiar with Kotlin and am not sure why my app is crashing. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

```
 fun progressBarAnimation(progressBar: ProgressBar, speed: TextView, mph: TextView, timer: TextView, times: TextView, yellowTimesBar: View, recTime1: TextView, recTime2: TextView, recTime3: TextView) {
// we will increase the max after each milestone has been hit
progressBar.max = 60
// need ot set currentProgress val equal to current speed
var currentProgress = 0
while (currentProgress < progressBar.max) {
    ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", currentProgress)
        .setDuration(500)
        .start()
    currentProgress++
}

// this will make the display flash 3 times when we hit a speed milestone
Timer().schedule(500) {
    speed.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFE222"))
    mph.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFE222"))
    timer.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFE222"))

    when (currentProgress) {
        60 -> {
            times.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            yellowTimesBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            recTime1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
        100 -> recTime2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        120 -> recTime3.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
Timer().schedule(900) {
    speed.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
    mph.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
    timer.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
}
Timer().schedule(1300) {
    // Changes text color
    speed.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFE222"))
    mph.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFE222"))
    timer.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFE222"))
}
Timer().schedule(1700) {
    speed.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
    mph.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
    timer.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
}
Timer().schedule(2100) {
    speed.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFE222"))
    mph.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFE222"))
    timer.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFE222"))
}
Timer().schedule(2500) {
    speed.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
    mph.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
    timer.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
}
```

}

Comment: Use Logcat and examine the stack trace associated with your crash: https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html

Comment: It would be a helpful if we could get the crash from the logcat, if you can post it